# Getting TypeError when trying to download .zip from FTP server

Tags: python, ftp, download, ftplib

I am trying to download a .zip file from a FTP server and I keep getting this error:

```
File "C:/filename.py", line 37, in handleDownload
file.write(block)
TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'str'
```

Here's my code (borrowed from http://postneo.com/stories/2003/01/01/beyondTheBasicPythonFtplibExample.html):

```
def handleDownload(block):
    file.write(block)
    print ".",

ftp = FTP('ftp.godaddy.com') # connect to host
ftp.login("auctions") # login to the auctions directory
print ftp.retrlines("LIST")
filename = 'auction_end_tomorrow.xml.zip'
file = open(filename, 'wb')
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, handleDownload)
file.close()
ftp.close()
```

Comment: Running that code on Python 2.7 downloads the file successfully. Is this the entire code sample? All I added was the `import` statement: `from ftplib import FTP` and it works correctly for me.

Comment: The variable called "block" (has a value, not shown in the code provided) is supposed to be a file object, not a string (fairly obvious).  If you include more of the code, I may be able to offer you more assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce this myself, but I have an idea of what's happening -- I'm just not sure *how* it's happening.  Hopefully someone can chime in.  Note that `file` isn't passed through to handleDownload, and `file` is also the name of a builtin type.  If `file` were left as the builtin, then you'd get exactly this error:

```
>>> file
<type 'file'>
>>> file.write("3")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'str'
```

So I think some of the problem is a confusion between `file`, the built-in, and `file`, the opened file itself.  (Probably using a name other than `"file"` is a good idea here.)  Anyway, if you simply use

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, file.write)
```

and ignore the `handleDownload` function entirely, it should work.  Alternatively, if you wanted to keep the dots printing every block, you could be a little fancier, and write something like

```
def handleDownloadMaker(openfile):
    def handleDownload(block):
        openfile.write(block)
        print ".",
    return handleDownload
```

which is a function which *returns* a function that points at the right file.  After that,

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR' + filename, handleDownloadMaker(file))
```

should work too.

Comment: Boom, great stuff, the second solution with the new function worked for me, just had to add the directory I wanted to write to into the line: file = open(filename, 'wb').

The first solution also worked, but when I checked the downloaded file it was corrupted, so perhaps the file I was downloading was too large not to be downloaded in separate bits.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Hi,just read your answer,I am trying to write to file onftp=FTP('domain name')
>>> ftp.login('user','pass')
>>> file11=open('CallXml.xml','w')
>>> file11.write('Hello World')
>>> file11.write('This is xyz here')
>>> file11.write('Glad to talk to you all')
>>> file11.close()
>>> file11=open('CallXml.xml','r')                             content=file11.read()  print content it prints correct content but when i log in to godaddy and check file it's not updated please let me knw why it's not updating on file on godaddy server?